# Add Read more button to view Gridview Description text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that fetches Description text from the database and once it's over some text limit, I want the Gridview to let users click "Read more" from where they can see the full text without having to navigate to a new url. Thank you in advance.
My Gridview Columns are as follows:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"  />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" SortExpression="Source" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Message" SortExpression="Message" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" SortExpression  ="Date"  />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add ItemTemplate with a Lable Control and LinkButton as read more in Gridview Like:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text='<%#((string)Eval("ColumnName")).Length<20?Eval("ColumnName"):((string)Eval("ColumnName")).Substring(0,20)+"..." %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("question") %>' Width="100"></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible='<%#SetVisibility(Eval("ColumnName"),20) %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Read More...</asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here Lable text it will contain only 20 char and link button will show Read More but Lable tooltip contain all characters of that column. On Link Button click we fire an event to show all data in that Label.

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Read More Link Button from Gridview on Click
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = lb.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            //Finding the description Text Lable
            Label qst = row.FindControl("Label20") as Label;
            // Setting Link Button Text 
            lb.Text = (lb.Text == "Read More...") ? "Hide..." : "Read More...";
            //Swaping tooltip value to text and vices versa as Tooltip has all charecters
            string temp = qst.Text;
            qst.Text = qst.ToolTip;
            qst.ToolTip = temp;
        }
protected bool SetVisibility(object Desc, int length)
        {
            return Desc.ToString().Length > length;
        }
```

Hope this will help you to find out your solution.

***Updates:***

It seems Your Column has null value to handle this you can check for null and then convert :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ColumnName")==DBNull.Value ? string.Empty :(((string)Eval("ColumnName")).Length<20?Eval("ColumnName"):((string)Eval("ColumnName")).Substring(0,20)+"...")  %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("question") %>' Width="100"></asp:Label>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ColumnName")==DBNull.Value ? false :SetVisibility(Eval("ColumnName"),20) %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Read More...</asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I added the ItemTemplate as you advised and then used the aspx.cs code too but it's not loading the page correctly. I get an error message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'. and it highlights the code 
Line 110:    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text='<%#((string)Eval("Message")).Length<20?Eval("Message"):((string)Eval("Message")).Substring(0,20)+"..." %>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("question") %>' Width="100"></asp:Label>

Comment: @anoj seems you have Null values in your DB column, so to handle this I added an update please try out that. If any issue, do inform me.

Comment: I mentioned for label text means in ASPX code of  Label, Text  attribute like that second one inside, Visible attribute of LinkButton.

Comment: Now, My Error is this:
Type 'About' already defines a member called 'SetVisibility' with the same parameter types

And it highlights to: 
Line 132:    protected bool SetVisibility(object Desc, int length)

Comment: Just found the reason and it was because I had defined SetVisibility method twice. Now, it works just fine. Many thanks Rojalin!

Comment: it's my pleasure helping you out.

Comment: One more question as it seems like I have lost the ability to Edit the Message field from the gridview itself!

Comment: it's a label control which will not be able to edit. Add edit template for that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a linkbutton and binding the message in the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Bind("Message") %> - <asp:linkbutton id="btnReadMore" runat="server" causesvalidation="false" commandname="readmore" commandargument="<%# Bind("MessageId") %>"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The logic for the link button can then  popup a

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "readmore")
        {
            Session["messageid"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("popuppage.aspx?id=" + Session["messageid"].ToString() + "");
        }
    }
```

In the popuppage.aspx will be logic to fetch the complete message using the messageid from the Query string.

Comment: I can't even bind the hyperlink to the gridview column "Message". I get an error saying "A call to bind must be assigned to a Property of Control inside Template". Can you please help?